# Postgresql Log Connection

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-4, postgresql-9.1

Is it normal if I have this :

```
2013-09-24 12:08:24 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:24 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59878
2013-09-24 12:08:24 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59879
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59880
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59881
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59882
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59883
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.92 port=58015
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection received: host=xx.x.xx.91 port=59885
2013-09-24 12:08:25 WIT LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxxxxx database=xxxx
```

in my postgresql-9.1-main.log? FYI, I have turned on the option 'log_connection' in postgresql.conf file, but I wonder is it normal if my application (I using laravel) keep creating connection (probably 15 times every second) with different port?

Also, my application become *very* heavy on load. Is it any relation with that log?

Laravel or Postgresql issues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never a good sign to see such log. Creating a new connection costs a lot.

You can try to add pgPool or pgBouncer (or any other middleware) for connection pooling. But for the best performance you need to manage a connection pool inside your app.

And it is not a Postgres issue - it does not implement connection pooling, leaving it to middleware or application themselves.